# Adding filename variable into HTML string in Python

Tags: html, string, variables, iframe, python-3.4

I've searched and can't find a solution to this. I'm trying to have the python code loop through a directory for .mht files. Upon finding files it will write an iframe html code to a file pointing to the .mht's. I'm having trouble defining the iframe code to be written and include the filename variables in the src.

> ```
> htmlframe = '''<iframe src="'%s.mht'" class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%"></iframe><br>''' % os.path.basename
> ```

The error I get is below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):File "move.py", line 52, in <module>
> htmlframe = '''<iframe src="'%s.mht'" class="iframe" scrolling="no"
> frameborder="0" style="width:100%"></iframe><br>''' % os.path.basename
> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
> ```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You should try to quote the `%` with `%%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rather complex string replacement operations, you should look at template engines. With such an engine it is usually much easier to keep the overview and to make modifications later on. A very simple one is built into the standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings

Is suffices most of the time!

Example:

```
from string import Template

s = """<iframe src="$filename" class="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>"""
t = Template(s)
print t.substitute(filename="foobar.mht")
```

Test:

```
python template.py
<iframe src="foobar.mht" class="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: I get invalid synatx on the t.substitute when trying that.

Comment: I executed with Python 2.7. What are you using? Remember, `print()` is a function is Python 3.

Comment: Just use `print(t.substitute(filename="foobar.mht"))` then and next time maybe add `python3` as a tag to your question? :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry! Didn't realize there was a large difference between 2.7 and 3.4, I'm still just learning. Do you know how to take the `filename=foobar.mht` and turn that into a variable to whichever file name the loop is on? I've looked at Pythons variables and it leads me to os.path.basename but I can't figure out how to implement it.